# How do you link multiple X input images to a single ground truth image in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, pandas, data-augmentation

What I'm asking is basically manual data augmentation. I have some very specific data augmentation for my inputs so I have to create them first in another software instead of doing it on the fly. I have some basic idea on how to pair up my Xs and Ys. I would probably create an extra CSV file and pair X1_1, X1_2, X1_3, to Y1 and I will repeat this for Xn_1, Xn_2, Xn_3, Yn. During training, I would read and load the correct pair.

So far I have only experimented with 1 to 1 ground truth pairs or did automatic 10 crop so I am not exactly sure if this is the best practice. Can someone critique this method? Another thing I want to point out is Xn_1, 2 and 3 will be further augmented during the actual training process.

Comment: what do you mean by 'automatic 10 crop' ?

Comment: automatic 10 crop as in built-in helper functions, eg I use pytorch and it has its own data augmentation library called torchvision.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correctly. You can point many augmented images to their corresponding original label. But this is not a good pratice if you have large number of images.

"Another thing I want to point out is Xn_1, 2 and 3 will be further augmented during the actual training process."

It depends on you. But that will not be any useful(as they'll get more distorted after two distortion).

Comment: I think that might be an issue because if everything goes according to plan the final dataset will contain 7 million images and since I am doing unsupervised learning I could always grab more because data is easy to find.